# She admitted/admits that she had stolen

Tags: grammar, tense-agreement

Are my examples grammatically correct?

> 1. She admitted that she had stolen the money.
> 2. She admits that she had stolen the money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is grammatical. The second example would need something added to justify the perfect tense, for example:

> She admits she had stolen the money before she fled.